# sessionRepository in com.sparsh.conferencedemo.controllers.SessionController required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I was trying to create a simple CRUD spring boot application after watching an online course. But when i run the application it shown an error "Field speakerRepository in com.sparsh.conferencedemo.controllers.SpeakerController required a bean of type 'com.sparsh.conferencedemo.repositories.SpeakerRepository' that could not be found." I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Also I am new to the spring boot. So any help please. I am posting my code below.

This is my **SessionController**

```
package com.sparsh.conferencedemo.controllers;


import com.sparsh.conferencedemo.models.Session;
import com.sparsh.conferencedemo.repositories.SessionRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/sessions")
public class SessionController {

    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;

    @GetMapping
    private List<Session> list(){
        return sessionRepository.findAll();
    }
    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    private Session get(@PathVariable Long id){
        return sessionRepository.getOne(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Session create(@RequestBody final Session session){
        return sessionRepository.saveAndFlush(session);
    }

 @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id){
        sessionRepository.
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Session update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Session session){
        Session existingSesseion=sessionRepository.getOne(id);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(session, existingSesseion, "session_id");
        return sessionRepository.saveAndFlush(existingSesseion);
    }
}
```

This is my **SessionRepository** interface

```
package com.sparsh.conferencedemo.repositories;
import com.sparsh.conferencedemo.models.Session;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
public interface SessionRepository extends JpaRepository<Session, Long> {

}
```

This is my **pom.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sparsh</groupId>
    <artifactId>conference-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>conference-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my Model for Session

```
package com.sparsh.conferencedemo.models;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
@Entity(name="sessions")
public class Session {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long session_id;
    private String session_name;
    private String session_description;
    private String session_length;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="session_speakers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "session_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "speaker_id")
    )
    private List<Speaker> speakers;

    public Session(){

    }

    public List<Speaker> getSpeakers() {
        return speakers;
    }

    public void setSpeakers(List<Speaker> speakers) {
        this.speakers = speakers;
    }


    public Long getSession_id() {
        return session_id;
    }

    public void setSession_id(Long session_id) {
        this.session_id = session_id;
    }

    public String getSession_name() {
        return session_name;
    }

    public void setSession_name(String session_name) {
        this.session_name = session_name;
    }

    public String getSession_description() {
        return session_description;
    }

    public void setSession_description(String session_description) {
        this.session_description = session_description;
    }

    public String getSession_length() {
        return session_length;
    }

    public void setSession_length(String session_length) {
        this.session_length = session_length;
    }
}
```

This is my main Application Class

```
package com.sparsh.conferencedemo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConferenceDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConferenceDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

These are the modules I am using in IntelliJ its an image link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PLvw.jpg

These are the error I am getting in the console

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-04-29 12:44:29.844  INFO 10572 --- [           main] c.s.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : Starting ConferenceDemoApplication on DESKTOP-JBQF1EV with PID 10572 (C:\Users\spars\OneDrive\Desktop\conference-demo\target\classes started by spars in C:\Users\spars\OneDrive\Desktop\conference-demo)
2020-04-29 12:44:29.859  INFO 10572 --- [           main] c.s.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-29 12:44:38.081  INFO 10572 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-29 12:44:38.174  INFO 10572 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-29 12:44:38.175  INFO 10572 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-04-29 12:44:38.582  INFO 10572 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-29 12:44:38.582  INFO 10572 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8561 ms
2020-04-29 12:44:39.083  WARN 10572 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sparsh.conferencedemo.repositories.SessionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2020-04-29 12:44:39.090  INFO 10572 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-04-29 12:44:39.647  INFO 10572 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-29 12:44:40.370 ERROR 10572 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field sessionRepository in com.sparsh.conferencedemo.controllers.SessionController required a bean of type 'com.sparsh.conferencedemo.repositories.SessionRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sparsh.conferencedemo.repositories.SessionRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you show us your service implementation?

Comment: @Sparsh, error is for ‘SpeakerController’, you are posting code for ‘SessionController’.. speaker vs session.. please revise your question

Comment: If you're following an online course where you've been told to use both `@RestController` and `@Component` I would suggest you to look for another one, or if this isn't the case, you should use only `@RestController`.Anyway this will not solve your problem, please revise your question like @Aman Garg said above.

Comment: I don't implement any service @varman

Comment: I highly doubt that that is actually your `pom.xml`. in your code you are using Spring Data JPA, but there is nothing in your `pom.xml` that is including those dependencies. So what you are showing here is probably not what you are currently using!

Comment: I am using spring-data-JPA.jar file by adding it into modules @M.Deinum

Comment: It should be part of your dependencies, not in your modules.

Comment: Please add the jpa dependency to your pom.xml and try <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have run into the same issue that I have following Dan Bunker's spring boot Pluralsight course?

Looks like the course is a little out of date now and the latest version of spring boot doesn't appear to work with the project setup. Specifically I think it's a problem with how we have defined the JpaRespositories such that they cannot be auto wired.

Obviously if we are both following a beginners course it's a little tricky to establish the root cause.

I downgraded my project to 2.1.9.RELEASE in pom.xml:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

And it worked! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem from Dan Bunker's spring boot Pluralsight course "Spring Framework 2: Creating Your First Spring Boot Application".
For newer Spring Boot versions (I am using 2.7.17) you need to comment out Autowired from both SessionsController and SpeakersController:

```
public class SessionsController {
    //@Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;
...

public class SpeakersController {
    //@Autowired
    private SpeakerRepository speakerRepository;
```